# What does "The culture is lit and I had a ball" mean in a Lana Del Rey song?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

I'm listening to [Lana Del Rey's song, the greatest](https://youtu.be/LrSX_OcpeJg?t=447), and she says:

> The culture is lit and I had a ball.

What does she mean?

Comment: *And then there’s [her most millennial line](https://time.com/5667705/lana-del-rey-norman-rockwell-lyrics-explained/) yet: **“The culture is lit, and if this is it, I had a ball / I guess that I’m burned out after all.”** Her play on words turns the phrase on its head, skewering the youthful slang term “lit” and leaning into the nihilistic burnout instead.* I don't know this "youthful slang term", but that should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: [...The Teen Slang Dictionary for Parents:](https://www.verywellfamily.com/a-teen-slang-dictionary-2610994#:~:text=Teen%20slang%20words%20may%20be,fit%20in%20with%20their%20peers.&text=Lit%20%2D%20Amazing%2C%20cool%2C%20or,%22%20or%20%22Oh%20my%20God%22) ***Lit** - Amazing, cool, or exciting.* And ***I had a ball*** = *I really enjoyed it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lana's singing](https://genius.com/Lana-del-rey-the-greatest-lyrics) about "those nights" in a variety of nostalgic places. "Lit", as mentioned, is very recent slang, meaning not just "outstanding" but especially "exciting", "high energy", or "wild"--"uninhibited", in an enjoyable way. "The culture" is becoming increasingly slang for what might have been called "the vibe" or "the community" in previous decades--for example, I can say "the culture was wack" about a party populated by people I find weird or corny.

When Lana sings "the culture is lit", it specifically means the people, parties, and places she interacted with/was part of were high energy, wild, exciting, and uninhibited, likely partying hard & partying often.

This is supported by the following lyrics which extend the implicit flame metaphor in the slang term "lit":

```
Those nights were on fire
We couldn't get higher
```

While "high" doesn't *necessarily* mean high on drugs, the overall effect of the lyrics is to describe a rowdy, euphoric environment Lana left.

It's worth noting that Lana uses the present tense "is" to describe "the culture"--even though she's not part of it any more, the culture's still there; she just stepped away from it.

"I had a ball" is much more straightforward; simply meaning she had a great time.

Answer (score 4):

"Lit" is very recent (2010s) teen slang.  It means "outstanding".

"I had a ball" is older (1920s) slang meaning "I had a very good time".

There seems to be some sense of irony in her use of these slang expressions from different times, but a literary analysis is beyond this answer.

It is worth noting that two years later, "Lit" is now very dated, and very old-fashioned.